# How to test imported custom font in XCTest (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

**Hi everyone!**
I imported custom font in project.
How can I test it with the text in the text field?
For example I have text field with text = "Stack overflow", with font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 17).
How can I check that text = "Stack overflow" has font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 17)? Have you any ideas, how to implement this in XCTest?

**Extensions**

---

```
import UIKit

extension UIFont {

    static func robotoRegular (size: CGFloat) -> UIFont? {
        return UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: size)
    }

    static func robotoBold (size: CGFloat) -> UIFont? {
        return UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: size)
    }

}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you be unit testing a class which uses those fonts?

I would suggest that you have a custom label subclass which you expect to be that font. The class and tests would look like this:

```
class CustomLabelWithFont: UILabel {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setStyle()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func setStyle() {
    self.font = .robotoBold(size: 20)
}
}
```

The tests file would look like so

```
class TestTestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testFontSetting() throws {
        let customLabel = CustomLabelWithFont(frame: .zero)
        XCTAssertEqual(customLabel.font, .robotoBold(size: 20))
        XCTAssertNotEqual(customLabel.font, .systemFont(ofSize: 20))
    }
}
```

You can also test your UIFont extension directly if you wish. There wouldn't be much utility in this aside from checking that the nobody has accidentally changed the font logic

```
func testFontItself() throws {
    let expectedFont: UIFont = .robotoBold(size: 20)!
    XCTAssertEqual(expectedFont, UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20))
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks  for the detailed answer! MARK: - It's not a good practice to use force unwrapping '!', it has tendency to crash. In tests it's might be ok, but in general the suggestion is: let expectedFont = UIFont.robotoBold(size: 20). Thank you! :) @Andrei T